# Lightdm sometime fails to autologin

Tags: lightdm, autologin

We have some kiosks which uses lightdm with autologin. Autologin sometime does not work, this happens randomly after reboot, mostly it works but sometimes it fails. Instead of autologin login screen appears. User needs to enter login and password, this is bad on kiosk.

When it fail I can see in `journalctl -u lightdm` this:

```
úno 01 04:00:39 rockpi-4b systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
úno 01 04:00:39 rockpi-4b lightdm[580]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
úno 01 04:00:39 rockpi-4b systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
úno 01 04:00:41 rockpi-4b lightdm[785]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
úno 01 04:00:41 rockpi-4b lightdm[785]: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
úno 01 09:01:22 rockpi-4b lightdm[2689]: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): check pass; user unknown
úno 01 09:01:22 rockpi-4b lightdm[2689]: pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=
```

When I restart lightdm `systemctl restart lightdm` it starts working (autologin successfull):

```
úno 01 09:52:16 rockpi-4b systemd[1]: Starting Light Display Manager...
úno 01 09:52:16 rockpi-4b lightdm[3180]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
úno 01 09:52:16 rockpi-4b systemd[1]: Started Light Display Manager.
úno 01 09:52:17 rockpi-4b lightdm[3205]: Error getting user list from org.freedesktop.Accounts: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.Accounts was not provided by any .service files
úno 01 09:52:17 rockpi-4b lightdm[3205]: pam_unix(lightdm-autologin:session): session opened for user pi by (uid=0)
```

What does mean that *pam_unix* error?

```
pam_unix(lightdm:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=:0 ruser= rhost=
```

I am using debian buster aarch64 on rockpi-4b (kernel 5.10.103+)

How can I fix that error, is it bug or some misconfiguration between *pam* and *lightdm*?

Comment: if you search for `lightdm autologin fails` you'll find that it's common ... one workaround apparently is to set the `autologin-user-timeout` to 5 seconds or so ...

Comment: Does it show login screen when I set `autologin-user-timeout`? I want to hide login screen during 5s timeout.

Comment: I don't know, I've never had the issue